# KMeansClustering Initialization

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I have a problem. I am using comirva package for speech recognition. I extracted MFCC coefficients from an audio file. After this operation I do not know how can continue. I have learned comirva.audio.util.kmeans.KMeansClustering class has to be used after MFCC. And then comirva.audio.util.gmm.GaussianComponent class has to be used. But I do not know how can I initialize KMeansClustering class and then GaussianComponent class and then what has to be done. Please have you got any idea, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u will transform your MFCC coefficient to a pointList (a class from comirva), then u creat a k-MeansClustering(nCluster,pointList);
u run it: kmeans.run();

then to create a GaussianComponent u can do:
gc = new GaussianComponent(kmeans.getWeight(ClusterIndex),kmeans.getMean(ClusterIndex),kmeans.getDiagCova . . );

if u want to creat directly a GMM u can do:
gmm = new GaussianMixture(kmeans.getWeights,kmeans.getMeans . . .);

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that specific library. But in order to initialized the centers for kmeans, several methods exist. The most common ones:

- random positions inside the limits of your data
- random data points

The first method usually is easier to achieve. For the second, you will have to create a random permutation of the data sample indices.

Comment: let me ask you a question @user492238 mfcc coefficients are 20X20 feature matrix for an audio, how can you create random data points. I do not understand what I have to this feature matrix

Comment: what the 20x20 matrix describes is up to the application, which created the matrix. It could be anything. So, I suggest to try to find out in the documentation of the product.